# Using pre-trained sentence embeddings in PyTorch

Tags: lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

**[Original post, see below for edited]**

I am new to PyTorch, and trying to perform a sentence classification task in it.

I have averaged out the word embeddings in each sentence (glove embeddings) to form the sentence embedding. Hence, the dimension of each sentence embedding is the same. As per my understanding, since I already have the embeddings I don't need the embedding layer before using the LSTM. 
My model is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.autograd as autograd
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class LSTM1(nn.Module):

def __init__(self,args):
    super(LSTM1,self).__init__()
    self.args = args
    self.hidden_dim = args.hidden_dim
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(args.embed_dim, args.hidden_dim)
    self.hidden2tag = nn.Linear(args.hidden_dim, 2)
    self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

def init_hidden(self):
    return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1,1, self.hidden_dim).cuda()),
        autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1,1, self.hidden_dim).cuda()))

def forward(self,embeds):
    embeds = autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(embeds[0]).float().cuda())
    lstm_output, self.hidden = self.lstm(embeds.view(1, 1, -1), self.hidden)
    tag_space = self.hidden2tag(lstm_output.view(1, -1))
    scores = F.log_softmax(tag_space)
    return scores
```

And I pass the sentences in the form of embeddings as follows:

```
model = model.LSTM1(args).cuda()
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-5)

optimizer.zero_grad()

for epoch in range(20):
    for i in range(len(sentences)):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        model.hidden = model.init_hidden()
        target = prepare_targets(tag_phrase[i],tag_to_ix,1) #Gets a Variable(long tensor) for the target, single value (either 0 or 1)
        score = model(sentences[i]) #sentences[i] is the embedding of sentence i

        loss = criterion(score,target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

My doubts:

1. So the embedding goes into the model, where in the forward function it gets converted to a Variablle(float tensor), and hence an appropriate input for the LSTM. This is my understanding of things. Is this correct?
2. I am backpropagating after every sentence, so does that make each sentence a separate batch? How do I split the sentences into batches and what changes do I need to make in the model then?
3. What is the most appropriate way to use pre-trained sentence embeddings in PyTorch?
4. If this code seems correct, then the problem I'm facing is that everything is getting classified into a single class out of the two. Any suggestions to resolve this error?

Thank you.

**[EDIT] Improved Code**

```
embeddings = torch.from_numpy(embeddings).float().cuda()
args.embed_num=embeddings.size(0)
args.embed_dim=embeddings.size(1)

seq = [i for i in range(13000)]
seq_tensor = torch.LongTensor(seq).cuda() #Index tensor corresponding to the embedding.

target = prepare_targets(tag_phrase[:13000],tag_to_ix,1)

train_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(seq_tensor.cuda(),target.data.cuda())
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)

model = model2.LSTM1(args,embeddings, 3).cuda()
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-5)

for epoch in range(1000):
    avg_loss=0.
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader,0):
        seq, target = data
        seq_var, target = autograd.Variable(seq.cuda()), autograd.Variable(target.cuda())
        correct=0
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        model.hidden=model.init_hidden()
        score=model(seq_var)
        loss = criterion(score,target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_lis.append(epoch)
        losses.append(loss.data[0])
        _,predicted = torch.max(score.data,1)
        correct += (predicted == target.data).sum()
        print i, correct
```

**model:**

```
class LSTM1(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,args,embeddings, layers):
        super(LSTM1,self).__init__()
        self.num_layers=layers
        self.args = args
        self.hidden_dim = args.hidden_dim
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(args.embed_num, args.embed_dim)
        self.embed.weight = nn.Parameter(embeddings)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(args.embed_dim, args.hidden_dim, num_layers=self.num_layers)
        self.hidden2tag = nn.Linear(args.hidden_dim, 2)
        self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

    def init_hidden(self):
        return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers,1, self.hidden_dim).cuda()),
            autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers,1, self.hidden_dim).cuda()))

    def forward(self,sentence):
        embeds = self.embed(sentence)
        lstm_output, self.hidden = self.lstm(embeds.view(len(sentence), 1, -1), self.hidden)
        tag_space = self.hidden2tag(lstm_output.view(len(sentence), -1))
        scores = F.log_softmax(tag_space)
        return scores
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, perhaps, in `autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(embeds[0]).float().cuda())` - you don't need `.float()` since `embeds` is already a float tensor. By the way, combining word vectors to form sentence vector is okay but then why you need RNN to generate sentence representations? Please review what you are doing carefully.
2. Yes, you are following stochastic gradient descent (running backprop after every sentence). To know how to use mini-batch gradient descent, you can see any language model based pytorch example. For example, [snli](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/snli) is a good example of text classification.
3. It depends on how you want to use it. I believe, there is no concept of "most appropriate way" of using pre-trained sentence embeddings in pytorch.
4. Your code has severe issues. For example, the LSTM in your model is not doing anything! Moreover, if you want to debug your code, I would suggest you to print the loss values and check if the loss value is going down with more and more iterations. If not, then you need to find out why your model is not learning anything.

Suggestion: From your questions, it looks like you are novice in pytorch. So, I want to recommend you to go through the official tutorials and examples before moving forward.

Comment: Thanks Wasi, 
1. I am not trying to generate sentence representations, I want to use these embeddings for a further sentence classification.
2. I have changed the model to a mini-batch based model now.
4. Can you please tell me why is the LSTM not doing anything according to you, what have I done wrong here?

Thanks a lot! I'll update my code with the new one.

Comment: I have updated the code, please take a look! I studied a lot of pytorch tutorials and examples. 

In this new code, I am passing a sentence embedding matrix as the embedding layers initial weights. The indexes of the sentences and the corresponding targets for the sentence classification are being passed as LongTensors inside the model. The whole computation is being done in mini-batches.

I framed my code on the SNLI and pytorch website examples.

Comment: @codeninja did you print the loss value after each mini-batch iteration? can you print the list `losses` and check if the loss value is going down with more and more iteration?

Comment: You're right, it isn't training. After the first epoch, I printed the value of losses after each mini batch iteration. The values stagnate around one point, moving ever so slightly up and down. 
iter0: 0.696107327938
iter1: 0.693988800049
iter2: 0.696617126465
iter3: 0.694681763649
iter4: 0.695053875446

Although, the average value of loss in every epoch goes down for the first few epochs then becomes constant. I was plotting the epoch loss earlier, hence thought that it was training. But it doesn't seem to be.  Any suggestions about what could be wrong with the new code?